# Creating a C# application to configure printer page settings

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, registry, printers

I am looking to deploy a c# application at my workplace which defines the default paper size. Nothing too special. It works by calling windows.win32 and using the registry class to write to the registry.

Despite my best efforts, I have been unable to find the relevant registry entries in order to set the paper size and registered printers. Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing registry settings is not the supported way to do this.

The correct way is to use the [`DEVMODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure.

The remarks at the bottom of the [`DocumentProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183576%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function describe the correct way to merge a new setting (such as paper size) with the existing configuration.

Don't worry that it describes how to change the settings for your application.  Replace the last step (`CreateDC`) with calling the [`SetPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145082%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function at [level 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162851%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to change the global defaults for that printer (or use level 9 to change the per-user defaults).

Doing this would be much easier in C++, since you can use the Windows-provided header files.  The structures involved are very complex, and getting the right p/invoke definitions would be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to change printer parameters is through the Win32 [`DEVMODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) structure during the printing process. The driver itself is responsible for filling in the defaults, and is generally configured through its property page.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the settings you want exist.

I found this

> I don't know about the general settings.My guess it depends on application and driver you use. At least I know for sure that some
>   printer drivers have their own default settings (hard-coded or set in registry).
>   Some settings are set through *.ppd files.
>
> Here is IE printer settings you can play with:
>
> [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
>
> Value : type Description
>   PageOrientation : REG_DWORD Specifies page orientation. Valid settings are 1=portrait, 2=landscape. Default setting is 1.
>   PrintQuality : REG_DWORD Specifies print quality. Valid settings are 1=draft, 2=final. Default setting is 1.
>   PaperSize : REG_DWORD Specifies paper size. Valid settings are 1=letter, 5=Legal, 9=A4, 13=B5.Default setting is 1.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/settings-dafault-paper-size-registry-t528995.html

Comment: not to mention browsers I've used remember the last settings sadly leaving it in landscape to waste paper the next time! argh!