# Controle Printer setting using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, thermal-printer

I was Introduced to "winspool.drv" not long ago and I was able to use it to change the default printer on windows but can I do more than that like adding or changing the printer setting it self.
for example the following pic has a printer that have 3 papers' sizes, can I change the manual feed from 80(72.1)*297 to 80(72.1)*3276.
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqqfH.png)

example two: add new paper size and orientations.

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1cej.png)

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [Set Printer Feature programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14140412/9014308), [Creating a C# application to configure printer page settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7433515/9014308), [Programmatically add custom paper size to printer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72ea2e81-56d2-4b00-a161-8a1177e3821b/), [How to override Custom Papersize in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39209126/9014308)

Comment: @kunif  thank you. I think it will take some time to go through the whole documentation.